# Imported libaries causing overlap

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make an interface using tkxui and tkinter for the modules it doesn't cover (Label, anchors etc)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO
from tkinter import *
import tkxui

win = tkxui.Tk(display=tkxui.FRAMELESS, defaultBorder=True)
win.geometry("700x400")
win.title("Window Title")
win.minsize(700, 400)
win.center()

URL = "http://www.universeofsymbolism.com/images/ram-spirit-animal.jpg"
u = urlopen(URL)
raw_data = u.read()
u.close()

im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
```

When running this code I get `AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'`(line 18)  as Traceback. It seems like tkinter and PIL are overlapping with the open function.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by importing the needed tkinter modules like this:

```
from tkinter.constants import *
```

and

```
from tkinter import Label
```